# Проблема с позиционированием блоков

Tags: css, вёрстка

Вот верстка дива где имеется ранее упомянутая проблема.

```css
#commonbackground {
  /* Общий большой div для бэкграунда*/
  height: 1952px;
  width: 1170px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}
#divcategorydescript {
  /* div для картинки с описанием категории*/
  width: 878px;
  height: 324px;
  float: left;
}
.forsingleitem {
  float: left;
}
.divpic {
  /*Дивы для блока с "изображением товара"*/
  background-color: #d1d3d4;
  width: 290px;
  height: 236px;
  font-family: 'Supermolot Light', Arial;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 36px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  color: #ececed;
}
.divgoodsname {
  /* Дивы с названием и ценой товара (белая полоса)*/
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 290px;
  height: 88px;
  margin-left: 2px;
}
#picpromo {
  /*Див с большим изображением "заголовок промо - товара"*/
  width: 586px;
  height: 650px;
  margin-top: 976px;
  margin-left: 585px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="commonbackground">
  <!--Общий большой див для бэкграунда-->

  <div id="divcategorydescript">
    <!--Див для картинки с описанием категории-->
    <img id="categorydescriptpic" src="./pics/bikeincategory.jpg" alt="Pic">
    <div id="categorydescript">ОПИСАНИЕ КАТЕГОРИИ
      <br><span id="shorttextaboutcategory">Краткий текст о категории</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="forsingleitem">
    <!--Див для одного товара с описанием и ценой-->
    <div class="divpic">
      <div class="goodspic">Изображение
        <br>товара</div>
      <div class="cornerdiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divgoodsname">
      <div class="goodsnamestr">Название товара</div>
      <div class="pricedigits">4 540<span class="pricedigitsrub">руб.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div id="picpromo">
    <!--Див для изображения с Промо-товаром-->
    <img id="promopicture" src="./pics/WakeboardPromoBackground.jpg" alt="Picture">
    <div id="promoheader">ЗАГОЛОВОК
      <br>ПРОМО-ТОВАРА
      <br><span id="promodescription">Описание промо-товара</span>
    </div>
    <div id="promopricedigits">4 540<span id="promopricedigitsrub">руб.</span> 
    </div>
    <a href="#">
      <div id="takepeekcategory">Посмотреть +</div>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
<!--Конец общего большого дива для бэкграунда-->
```

Comment: css бы еще увидеть

Comment: с комментов можно удалить :)

Comment: Я упустил ширину общего дива 1170px;

Comment: Сформулируйте саму проблему. Что вам не нравится в позиционировании ваших блоков. Что хотите получить?

Comment: Прошу прощения, думал из предыдущего вопроса информация видна.

Comment: Я ничего не знаю про предыдущий вопрос. Можете добавить на него ссылку, но в любом случае сделайте этот вопрос самодостаточным.

Comment: Мне нужно в общем диве выводить 17 дивов с отдельными товарами. Вторая большая картинка позиционирована абсолютно, чтобы быть в определенном месте по дизайну. При выводе 17 блоков четыре из них лезут под абсолютно позиционированную картинку. А они должны обходить ее зигзагом. Это, наверное, нереально. Но у меня такой дизайн в дипломе. Заранее большое спасибо за ответы:)

Comment: @лихаим совет: переходим по ссылке [править](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/535594/edit) (внизу вашего поста), прокручиваем немного вниз и под блоком с кодом есть ссылка "редактировать пример кода", редактируем и подгоняем до того вида который у вас (чтобы мы видели саму проблему), жмем кнопку "Вставить в сообщение", и сохраняем отредактированный пост

Comment: А вот сейчас на страничке здесь  все как у меня. Не знаю, кто это сделал, но огромное спасибо:)

Comment: Где упомянута проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вместо абсолютного позиционирования использовать `float:right;`:

1. Блок с `float:right;` поставьте первым.
2. Чтобы блок с заголовком занял всю свободную ширину экрана, назначьте ему `overflow: hidden;`.
3. Чтобы ряды товаров не скомкались при встрече с промо-блоком, нужно либо подобрать высоту промо-блока, либо расставлять `clear:left;` через медиа-запросы. Медиа-запросы дольше считать и дольше пересчитывать, если в макете поменяется какой-нибудь размер. Лучше подобрать высоту промо-блока.

---

### Вариант с расчётом высоты промо-блока

Это пример. Под свой макет пересчитайте размеры самостоятельно.

```css
/* чтобы браузер вычислял размеры блоков, включая border и padding внутрь width и height: https://webref.ru/layout/learn-html-css/box-model */
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

#commonbackground {
  /* общий фон */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  overflow: hidden; /* заставляем обернуть все плавающие блоки */
  width: 100%;
}
#divcategorydescript {
  /* картинка с описанием категории */
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#picpromo {
  /* блок с промо-товаром */
  background: orange;
  float: right;
  height: 426px; /* = 100px #divcategorydescript height + 2px .forsingleitem margin-top + 236px .divpic height + 88px .divgoodsname height */
  width: 290px;
}
.forsingleitem {
  /* блок с одним из товаров */
  float: left;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
.divpic {
  /* блок изображением товара */
  background: #d1d3d4;
  color: #ececed;
  font-family: 'Supermolot Light', Arial;
  font-size: 32px;
  height: 236px;
  line-height: 36px;
  width: 290px;
}
.divgoodsname {
  /* блок с названием и ценой товара (белая полоса) */
  background: #fff;
  height: 88px;
  line-height: 36px;
}

#divcategorydescript,
#picpromo,
.divpic,
.divgoodsname {
  /* отступ внутри блока для красоты */
  padding: 4px 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="commonbackground">
  <!--Общий большой див для бэкграунда-->

  <div id="picpromo">
    <!--Див для изображения с Промо-товаром-->
    <img id="promopicture" src="./pics/WakeboardPromoBackground.jpg" alt="Picture">
    <div id="promoheader">ЗАГОЛОВОК
      <br>ПРОМО-ТОВАРА
      <br><span id="promodescription">Описание промо-товара</span>
    </div>
    <div id="promopricedigits">4 540<span id="promopricedigitsrub">руб.</span> 
    </div>
    <a href="#">
      <div id="takepeekcategory">Посмотреть +</div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="divcategorydescript">
    <!--Див для картинки с описанием категории-->
    <img id="categorydescriptpic" src="./pics/bikeincategory.jpg" alt="Pic">
    <div id="categorydescript">ОПИСАНИЕ КАТЕГОРИИ
      <br><span id="shorttextaboutcategory">Краткий текст о категории</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="forsingleitem">
    <!--Див для одного товара с описанием и ценой-->
    <div class="divpic">
      <div class="goodspic">Изображение
        <br>товара</div>
      <div class="cornerdiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divgoodsname">
      <div class="goodsnamestr">Название товара</div>
      <div class="pricedigits">4 540<span class="pricedigitsrub">руб.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="forsingleitem">
    <!--Див для одного товара с описанием и ценой-->
    <div class="divpic">
      <div class="goodspic">Изображение
        <br>товара</div>
      <div class="cornerdiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divgoodsname">
      <div class="goodsnamestr">Название товара</div>
      <div class="pricedigits">4 540<span class="pricedigitsrub">руб.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="forsingleitem">
    <!--Див для одного товара с описанием и ценой-->
    <div class="divpic">
      <div class="goodspic">Изображение
        <br>товара</div>
      <div class="cornerdiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divgoodsname">
      <div class="goodsnamestr">Название товара</div>
      <div class="pricedigits">4 540<span class="pricedigitsrub">руб.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="forsingleitem">
    <!--Див для одного товара с описанием и ценой-->
    <div class="divpic">
      <div class="goodspic">Изображение
        <br>товара</div>
      <div class="cornerdiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divgoodsname">
      <div class="goodsnamestr">Название товара</div>
      <div class="pricedigits">4 540<span class="pricedigitsrub">руб.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="forsingleitem">
    <!--Див для одного товара с описанием и ценой-->
    <div class="divpic">
      <div class="goodspic">Изображение
        <br>товара</div>
      <div class="cornerdiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divgoodsname">
      <div class="goodsnamestr">Название товара</div>
      <div class="pricedigits">4 540<span class="pricedigitsrub">руб.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="forsingleitem">
    <!--Див для одного товара с описанием и ценой-->
    <div class="divpic">
      <div class="goodspic">Изображение
        <br>товара</div>
      <div class="cornerdiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divgoodsname">
      <div class="goodsnamestr">Название товара</div>
      <div class="pricedigits">4 540<span class="pricedigitsrub">руб.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="forsingleitem">
    <!--Див для одного товара с описанием и ценой-->
    <div class="divpic">
      <div class="goodspic">Изображение
        <br>товара</div>
      <div class="cornerdiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divgoodsname">
      <div class="goodsnamestr">Название товара</div>
      <div class="pricedigits">4 540<span class="pricedigitsrub">руб.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="forsingleitem">
    <!--Див для одного товара с описанием и ценой-->
    <div class="divpic">
      <div class="goodspic">Изображение
        <br>товара</div>
      <div class="cornerdiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divgoodsname">
      <div class="goodsnamestr">Название товара</div>
      <div class="pricedigits">4 540<span class="pricedigitsrub">руб.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Конец общего большого дива для бэкграунда-->
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41350/discussion-on-answer-by-gleb-kemarsky----).